# What is Azure CLI or RESTful API equivalent of Get-AzStorageUsage?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I checked Microsoft documentations but couldn't find the Azure CLI or RESTful API equivalent of `Get-AzStorageUsage`.

I need it to query current quota limits of our subscription using Ansible playbooks so I need either Azure CLI or RESTful API equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Azure CLI**

```
az storage account show-usage --location
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-show-usage

**RESTful API**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/locations/{location}/usages?api-version=2021-04-01
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/usages/list-by-location

Comment: I guess I didn't look hard enough. Thanks!